# Como evitar possivel incompatibilidade no Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Bom dia pessoal,

Existe alguma escolha a se fazer na criação de uma aplicação para que ela seja compativel com as versões do windows 7, 8 e 10 ?

Estou fazendo hoje como 32Bits, é o suficiente ?

Comment: Muito aberta. Compatível que você diz é aceitar no windows Xp? Compatível com arquitetura 32 bits?

Comment: versão 32 roda em 64 porem 64 não roda em 32, agora em relação a compatibilidade nas versõs do windows xp 7 vista 8 10 etc vai depender das dlls que utiliza e no  mais vc tem  fazer  o  teste em maquinas virtuais para ver se não dará nenhum  erro, po  bom de desenvolver em  c# no  windows forms é que sua compatbilidade maioria das vezes so vai depender da versão do  dot.net framework  instalado na maquina do  cliente

Comment: Obrigado @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons

Comment: Como complemente ao comentário do @marcos [veja esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198873/os-compatibility-for-various-net-framework-versions)

Comment: Obrigado @lazyFox foi um otimo complemento